# Returning rows where 1 column is the same and other column is different

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sure this is very simple, but i'm struggling!

What i want to do is to return the ProductID from the table below where Mailed = True but only where ProductID has a single supplier.

In the example below, i need to return PRoductIDs 2 and 5 but not 1

```
+-----------+----------+-------------+
| ProductID | Supplier | CanBeMailed |
+-----------+----------+-------------+
|         1 | A        |      False  |
|         1 | B        |      True   |
|         2 | C        |      True   |
|         3 | C        |      False  |
|         4 | D        |      False  |
|         4 | E        |      False  |
|         5 | E        |      True   |
|         6 | F        |      False  |
+-----------+----------+-------------+
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for what you're after:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1,'A',0),
                 (1,'B',1),
                 (2,'C',1),
                 (3,'C',0),
                 (4,'D',0),
                 (4,'E',0),
                 (5,'E',1),
                 (6,'F',0)) V(ProductID, Supplier, Mailed))
SELECT ProductID
FROM VTE
GROUP BY ProductID
HAVING SUM(CASE Mailed WHEN 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT Supplier) = 1;
```

Comment: I think it should be count distinct supplier. It's not clear enough.

Comment: @Lamu . . . I think `MIN(Supplier) <> MAX(Supplier)` usually has better performance.

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci you're right, it isn't clear enough, but with the sample data we have if `COUNT(DISTINCT Supplier)` and `COUNT(Supplier)` resulted in different values, that could mean a duplicated row. I imagine that the data the OP has provided is oversimplified, and but left `COUNT` as it was, as this isn't as expensive as`COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Comment: Thansk for the advice, sorry i din't make my initial question clear enough as the mailed column is actually a true / false column

Comment: @Chris that's simple enough to change with a `CASE` expression. I've updated for your reference.

Comment: @Larnu Yep that works perfectly. Thanks for you help!